# How can I effectively hide cables under my carpet or around the room?

Tags: carpet, cables

Current situation:

I have recently hooked up my PC to my new room setup. The problem is, the LAN cable is exactly in the middle of the other side of the room. Here's a quick sketch of my room (horribly out of proportion):

[image]

The red line is the LAN cable, and the gray area is my carpet. You can see that on the other side of the room, the cable goes under the carpet. This is annoying in two ways:

- The cable is loose. If anyone slips on the carpet hard enough, it slips right out of my PC.
- The carpet has a pretty visible bulge.

Currently, without **a lot** of effort, I can't put the cable under the.. wooden thing (I do not know the name, here's an image:)

[image]

(Image source: [profhome-shop.de](https://www.profhome-shop.de/item/images/425/500x500/425-cx132-int1.jpg))

This is because I would need to rearrange my wardrobe and bed. Also, the cable would need to go under my heater, and I do not want to risk any damage to my cable from the heat.

So I pretty much have no idea.

- Is there any better way of arranging my cable around my room?
- Can I somehow hide the bulge on my carpet?

*(Note: WiFi is not an option ;) )*

Comment: Running cables under carpet is bad for the cables, and potentially bad for you (classic cause of fires, though it might be hard to start a fire with an ethernet cable)

Comment: That's a reason why i need a new solution :/ @Ecnerwal

Comment: The "wooden thing" = baseboard.  What does the threshold under the door look like?  Sometimes, a cable can go through a hollow metal (transition) threshold or carefully stapled and covered with a metal/plastic one with a very low profile that doesn't interfere with the door (such ones are often used in offices).

Comment: What about going under the floor (basement/crawlspace), or above the ceiling (attic)?

Comment: @Tester101 The LAN cable comes out of a wifi extender in the power socket. Moving it one floor lower will cause it to be an ugly cable going up  in the living room, and one floor higher it won't receive a strong enough signal.

Comment: Couldn't you plug the WiFi extender in closer to the PC?

Comment: @Tester101 I thought about that, 1. the signal strengh might be too weak, and 2. the ethernet cable is about 10m long, the PC is only about 1m from the power socket. I don't like managing long cables into small ones. I might consider buying a smaller ethernet cable, that might work.

Comment: @Tester101 Do you think [this one](http://www.howtogeek.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/04/654x406xDSC_0230.jpg.pagespeed.gp+jp+jw+pj+js+rj+rp+rw+ri+cp+md.ic.ZOeppz0sua.jpg) is a good choice? ;)

Comment: Buying a shorter cable would be a lot cheaper than a [Power-line communicator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power-line_communication#Indoor). ("Ethernet over power")

Comment: "If anyone slips on the carpet hard enough, it slips right out of my PC." That's probably a good thing, better than it staying very firmly connected and pulling your PC with it.

Answer (score 4):

Go up and over the door, and along the top of the wall. then down the wall to the computer. Use <s>wiremold</s> cable duct to make it neat. wiremold is a brand-name, I guess. Cable duct is more generic.

[image: Wiremold]

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look at it. Would you recommend a setup [like this](https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQNNLzeEKDs1E53Ptf-Y3GzioJ7MHSJmWoat8LUQqKYcDF8wjms), where the duct is in the edge of the wall?

Comment: Looks fine, though you need to see how that comes down the face of the wall, unless a dangling cable suits your taste. It's really a matter of taste/decor what specific system you choose. If your room happened to have "picture molding" you can often hide a cable in the top of that. Likewise, if you are willing/able to open up walls and drill holes, all cables can be concealed in the walls/ceiling/floor.

Comment: Maybe I should stop thinking complicated and just buy an internet usb stick ;)

Comment: ...or rearrange the room so the computer is near the wire ;-)

Comment: Look at the picture of the baseboard--not remotely flat on top.  While the cable could be run this way it wouldn't look neat.

Comment: @devRicher, An alternative is to go up over the door and back down along the other side of the door. You can then follow the baseboard around to your desk. This prevents having a cable coming down from the ceiling in the middle of the wall. Yet another alternative would be to get a longer cable and go all the way around the room. The position of the heater is not shown on the drawing, so we can not know where that needs to be avoided.

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly recommend that you first try a room rearrangement plan with the goal of getting the computer and the computer table closer to the lan cable location. The first step to doing this is to get some grid paper and draw out an accurate to scale outline of the room. Such as let three or four grid squares represent one foot of room dimension. Then make up paper shapes of each item in the room that match the size of each using the same grid scale factor.

You then work with the shapes to find ways that they will fit into the room. This prevents the need to repeatedly drag things around in the room until you find a layout that works. *(If your room sketch was accurate I am sure that you would have already had one or two answers recommending a layout. :-)*